# how to deal with this fundamental error in rust?

Tags: rust

> im writing a program to convert a number  to sorted reversed array of digits.
> eg : 23453 -> vec![5,4,3,3,2]
> but i got this error! and i cant fix this

```
error[E0599]: no method named `sorted` found for struct `Chars` in the current scope
    --> src/main.rs:2050:25
     |
2050 |   n.to_string().chars().sorted().map(|no| no.to_digit(10).unwrap() as u32).rev().collect::<Vec<u32>>()
     |                         ^^^^^^ method not found in `Chars<'_>`

error[E0277]: `Vec<u32>` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Display`
```

> here is my code,

```
fn sorted_rev_arr(n : u32) -> Vec<u32>{
  n.to_string().chars().sorted().map(|no| no.to_digit(10).unwrap() as u32).rev().collect::<Vec<u32>>()
}

fn main(){
  let random_number = 23453;
  println!("the new number in array is {}",sorted_rev_arr(random_number));
}
```

> can anybody help me to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Do you have a minimal workable example to show? I don't think two functions will do it as this is a scope/dependency issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `sorted` method in Rust iterators or `Vec`. You'll have to collect to a `Vec` first and then sort it:

```rust
fn sorted_rev_arr(n: u32) -> Vec<u32> {
    let mut digits = n
        .to_string()
        .chars()
        .map(|no| no.to_digit(10).unwrap() as u32)
        .collect::<Vec<u32>>();
    digits.sort();
    digits.reverse();
    digits
}
```

You can also do a reverse sort in one go:

```rust
fn sorted_rev_arr(n: u32) -> Vec<u32> {
    let mut digits = n
        .to_string()
        .chars()
        .map(|no| no.to_digit(10).unwrap() as u32)
        .collect::<Vec<u32>>();
    digits.sort_by(|a, b| b.cmp(&a));
    digits
}
```

Also, you need to use `{:?}` instead of `{}` to print a `Vec`.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=33744926e59af824e03a88942437377d)

Comment: Note that [`sorted()` exists on `itertools`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.sorted).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman: While a useful shorthand it is worth [noting](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/src/itertools/lib.rs.html#2593-2602) that `itertools::sorted()` basically does a `collect` into a `Vec`, an inplace sort, and then returns that as an iterator, so same runtime behavior as this answer.

Comment: @rodrigo Sure, I should have clarified that :) Just wanted to note because maybe the OP saw that somewhere (though maybe it was just stolen from Python :) )